# Can models improve the more you use them?

Tags: supervised-learning, active-learning, continual-learning

I came across this interesting question on Quora (someone else asked): [How can I penalize a deployed classifier for every wrong prediction in the production run? I want to implement an online model improvement for an ML algorithm.](https://qr.ae/pvLDJo)

While there is the word "online" in the title, in fact the post was referring to model weight updates while in production (i.e., "online", hence not referring to the opposite of batch learning known as "online learning", as suggested in the response). Since the tasks would be the same (i.e., no change in the classes or expected data), this is not a "continual learning" problem, either. However, I am led to believe it is *some* instance of "active learning", though used for model improvement purposes rather than just for labelling unlabelled data previously collected.

I do not think this actually falls under continuous training & deployment. Allow me to give an example for classification: the model is *in production* and receives an image, there is a human who reviews the machine's prediction (cat or dog) which turns out to be the wrong one, then the reviewer selects the ground-truth class and the model improves *as soon as* this feedback is provided.

What is the area in AI/ML which studies this type of models? Any leading studies or researchers studying such AI/ML problems in particular?

Now, by admission of my own failure to find (although I looked) relevant resources for self-help, I was wondering if I can query the neural circuits of this well-respected tribe for an opinion. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: This just seems like collecting more data. Also, unless your model is something quite simple with a closed form update equation, you will not be able to "improve as soon as this feedback is provided"

Comment: I am still not sure what branch of AI/ML deals with something like this type of problem.